# Scala equivalent of instanceOf Java and exception handling

Tags: unit-testing, scala, junit4

Just started using Scala for unit testing and am totally confused as to how exceptions are handled in Scala. Below is an example of a JUnit test.

```
class Test {
  @Test
  void someTest {
    try {
      //Something
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Assert.assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceOf IOException);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing in Scala, I tried

```
class Test {
  @Test def someTest {
    try {
      //Something
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => assertTrue(e.getCause().isInstanceOf[IOException])
    }
  }
}
```

But my IDE keeps complaining that `Method Apply is not a member of type Any`. I read about exception handling in Scala and found that you should use a pattern matcher and that there is [no exception handling in Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-4). How exactly does this work?

Comment: Can you, please, write exact code (without comments on the last line - the one, that with `case` statement)?

Comment: Saying that there is "no exception handling in Scala" makes about as much sense as saying "there are no structures in C++".  Of course there is; it does everything that Java does and more, more easily and safely.  It's _not exactly the same_, but that shouldn't be confused with _being absent_.

Comment: Well, I changed it as one of the exceptions was the IO.

Comment: @RexKerr: I was not saying that, I read it off the blog I liked too. Am still a newbie :)

Comment: I know you're not saying it.  I'm just saying that the blog's characterization is wrong.

Comment: You should really try [ScalaTest](http://scalatest.org) - code will suddenly become much easier to parse for human beings :) : `evaluating { /* code you want to test */ } should produce [IOException]`

Comment: But even for **JUnit** I can recommend to use `@Test(expected = classOf[IOException])`

Comment: Why use 1 line when you can use 13?

Comment: I want to actually answer the question instead of telling you to use something else. However, you did not specify what the IDE is, nor where *exactly* is the error. Also, IDEs on Scala are not always right, so it might just be possible the code is correct, and the IDE isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are testing scala code I suggest using something more scalish than jUnit like [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org).

```
import java.io.IOException

import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

object SomeCode
{
    def apply() = {
        throw new IOException
    }
}

class SomeTest
  extends FlatSpec
  with ShouldMatchers
{
    "Something" should "throw an IOException, TODO: why ?" in
    {
        intercept[IOException] {
            SomeCode()
        }
    }

    it should "also throw an IOException here" in
    {
        evaluating { SomeCode() } should produce [IOException]
    }
}

nocolor.run( new SomeTest )
```